# literal initialization of embeded struct with multiple fields

Tags: go

```
type fun struct {}

type starcraft struct {
    *fun // embedding struct
    mu sync.Mutex
}
```

I know I can literal initial struct startcraft as:

```
f := &fun{}
s := starcraft{f, *new(sync.Mutex)}
```

I don't like it, since:

a. I don't want to initialize sync.Mutex by myself

b. in this case there is a wasted copy using *new(sync.Mutex).

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why are you embedding a reference?

Comment: @rvignacio: there's nothing particularly wrong with embedding a pointer to a struct. It might be more convenient if that embedded type is always referenced via a pointer, so you don't need to selectively dereference it or worry about inadvertently creating copies.

Comment: @JimB, I thought so at first, but there seems to be no difference between embedding by reference or value (I believe the runtime resolves the derreferencing)... I'm going to write a question about that =P

Comment: @rvignacio I thought embedding by instance will cause a copy? Please correct me if I am wrong. Can you post your question link to here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name embedded structs:

```
s := starcraft{
    fun: f,
    mu:  *new(sync.Mutex),
}
```

You don't need to use `new` to create a zero value. If the type is already declared, you don't need to initialize it at all, or you can use the zero value.

```
s := starcraft{
    fun: f,
    mu:  sync.Mutex{},
}
```

And since the zero value for a Mutex is a valid, unlocked Mutex (http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex), you definitely don't need to initialize it, and can leave it out of the struct literal.

```
s := starcraft{
    fun: f,
}
```

On top of that, it's also very common to embed the Mutex and call `Lock` and `Unlock` directly on the outer struct.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded structs can be named, which suggests this method

```
f := &fun{}
s := starcraft{fun:f}
```

Which might be what you want

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HhVgtMgoFL)

Comment: thanks this is also a good answer, accepted JimB's for more information.